# Doing the same type of work with variables in c#

Tags: c#, picturebox

In my program there is a piece of code:

```
        bigbg1.Image = null;
        bigbg2.Image = null;
        bigbg3.Image = null;
        bigbg4.Image = null;
        bigbg5.Image = null;
        bigbg6.Image = null;
        bigbg7.Image = null;
        bigbg8.Image = null;
        bigbg9.Image = null;
```

where `bigbg` 1-9 is a variables of `PictureBox` type. How can I make this code shorter? I would like to use a function similar to the "`for`", but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Create an array or collection variable instead, basically... it's hard to give much more detail without more information about `bigbg*`

Comment: Do you mean `    for(int i=1; i<=9; i++)
    {
      "bigbg"+i.ToString()+."Image" = null;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using winforms, you can just iterate over your picturebox controls:

```
foreach(var pictureBox in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
    pictureBox.Image = null;
```

Comment: Perhaps with a `.Where` to filter on the beginning of the names? If you want *all* the picture boxes this code is perfect.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think that this solution, together with the `.Where` perfect for my program. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other posts, create an array and use the Linq ForEach method.

```
List<PictureBox> pbs = new List<PictureBox>();
pbs.AddRange(new [] { bigbg1, bigbg2, bigbg3, bigbg4, bigbg5, bigbg6, bigbg7, bigbg8, bigbg9 });
pbs.ForEach(p => p.Image = null);
```

**UPDATE**:

Here's a terse, compact syntax that makes use of the accepted answer and its comments:

```
this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
  .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("bigbg")).ToList()
    .ForEach(p => p.Image == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` and `for`:

```
pictureBox [] _pictureBox =   this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>();
for(int i=0; i<_pictureBox.lenght;i++)
{
_pictureBox[i] =null;
}
```